# Function 'ReadSecurity' from CSOM Online for CSOM 2013

Tags: permissions, csom, sharepoint-on-prem

Is there around way to use ReadSecurity/WriteSecurity on List from Sharepoint 2013? This method works in Sharepoint Online but not Sharepoint 2013. In C# code.
For online code it looks like this:

```
list.ReadSecurity = 1;
list.WriteSecurity = 2;
```

Comment: Did you try in 2013? what's the error/issue?

Comment: Function does not exit in 2013

Comment: Yeah. It does not exist in 2013. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f7d3c3fd-1386-4239-99ad-2b3d23babb0e/how-to-set-read-write-security-on-list-using-client-object-model?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: is it necessary to use CSOM on Onprem ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the List setting and In Advanced Setting do this:[image]

Comment: But im looking to do this in C# code, I have found this before.